# Why is the map value not updating?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this free function in my code :

```
void changeRanks(int n, map<int, double>& id_rank_map)
{
  cout << "n : " << n << endl;
  
  for(auto itr : id_rank_map)
  {
    itr.second = double(1) / double(n);
  }
}
```

I've verified that 'n' is not 0, but still each value in 'id_rank_map' is 0.00 even after the execution of the line inside the for loop, when accessed from the 'main' function.

How do I update this?

Comment: Try `auto &itr: id_rank_map`.

Comment: `itr` is also a confusing name since it's not an iterator.

Comment: *How do I update this?* -- Figure out what type is behind the `auto` statement, and you should see why it doesn't get updated.  Hint -- it isn't a reference.

Comment: @ShashankVijay -- Write a regular `for` loop using `std::begin()` and `std::end()` instead of a range-based one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a range based for loop, the variable left of the `:` is not an iterator, but the value itself:

```
for(auto v : id_rank_map)
```

spelling it out:

```
for(std::pair<const int, double> v : id_rank_map)
```

Written like this, now it is obvious, that in each iteration, a copy of the value is created, then modified, then thrown away. Change it to a reference, to avoid the copy, and modify the value stored in the container:

```
for(std::pair<const int, double>& v : id_rank_map)
// or
for(auto& v : id_rank_map)
```

Comment: @erenon What's the reason behind the const ness of the first of the pair?

Comment: @ShashankVijay With `auto` you get the same type as the variable you're copying from, so `auto v` is the same as `std::pair<const int, double> v` in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But while declaring the map, I haven't specified const, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ShashankVijay It doesn't matter if you declared it with a non-`const` `int`. The keys in `map`s are immutable. You can't change them. To change a key, you have to rip the node out of the `map` (or delete the entry) and then reinsert it with a new key.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That makes sense. Got it.